# Autocomplete with multipleSeparator not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am using this jQuery code for autocompletion.

The multiple selection is working fine in Firefox and Chrome, but NOT in IE.
Please suggest me a solution..

How can I populate corresponding id (unique id) corresponding to the searched text to a hidden variable...

**JavaScript**

```
    $().ready(function() {
        $("#course").autocomplete("ajax.php", {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            mustMatch: true,
            minChars: 0,
            multiple: true,
            highlight: false,
            multipleSeparator: ",",
            selectFirst: false
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="course" id="course" />
```

Comment: try adding document to your ready handler  $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: did u not got a `TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of null` error as u are passing nothing for `$()` ?

Comment: @Yoda .. NO.. Both will work..

Comment: Missing document in $( ... ).ready

Comment: @Warrior I got that error when I just executed the same ready method without passing document object in chrome's console.

Comment: Which internet explorer are you trying this on?  IE8? IE9? IE10?
Also which jQuery are you using?

Comment: what autocomplete widget are you using, it doesnt seem like the [jQuery ui one.](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote)

Comment: $(function(){
 /*yourcode*/
});
And, you could describe problem more detail with http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're in WordPress or something that may require an explicit wrapper but your autocomplete syntax looks just fine. Try putting the most explicit doc ready wrapper you can around it to see if that fixes it in IE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#course').autocomplete('ajax.php', {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    mustMatch: true,
    minChars: 0,
    multiple: true,
    highlight: false,
    multipleSeparator: ',',
    selectFirst: false
  });
});
```